# Ubuntu: Take actions when system temperature gets too high

Tags: ubuntu, shutdown, cooling

One of the CPU fans on my Compaq Presario laptop running Ubuntu 9.10 seems to have bit the dust. The fan is deep within the case and I intend to replace the laptop in the next 6 months so it's not worth replacing it. I have the laptop on a cooling pad and most of the time the system is fine, CPU temps around 90°-110°F. Occasionally, however, I'm seeing random lockups which I believe is due to the system overheating. How can I configure the system to:

1. Lower the CPU speed when the temperature reaches a certain level? (I.E. >110°F)
2. Shutdown the system when the tempature reaches a critical level? (And what would that be? >130°?)

Comment: (Better tag suggestions welcomed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use computertemp:

http://computertemp.berlios.de/

The last screenshot is exactly what you want (actions upon alarm):

http://computertemp.berlios.de/screenshots.php

As far as your goals:

(1) Adjusting CPU frequency: http://www.linux.it/~malattia/wiki/index.php/Cpufreqd (trigger this with a computertemp alarm)

(2) Clean shutdown at upper-limit temp: "shutdown -h now" as your triggered command

You might also need lm-sensors installed (or not, read the computertemp docs).

You can add it to your panel:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=805702

Finally, I feel compelled to suggest buying a MacBook or MacBook Pro as your next laptop.

Comment: @Alexander Burke: Believe me, I'd love to buy a MacBook. I use an iMac daily. However this laptop was a hand-me down, and I doubt I'll be buying a new one anytime soon :-(

Comment: I was going by "I intend to replace the laptop in the next 6 months". :)

If my solution solves your problem, please mark it as the answer!  :D

Comment: True. That's my *intention* at least :-) I haven't tried your suggestion yet but I will soon, and I most certainly will accept it if it works!

Comment: I should have mentioned, I *intended* to buy myself a new laptop for Christmas, and that didn't work out too well!

Comment: @Alex Hi, the http://computertemp.berlios.de/ URL redirects to an Admin panel user/pass prompt, can you please update the computertemp link ?

Comment: @SebMa It's been 12 years. The Internet changes, alas. Here's an Internet Archive snapshot from a week after my post: https://web.archive.org/web/20100317104714/computertemp.berlios.de

Comment: @Alex Thanks for the URL, now I know what computertemp was. One can use [psensor](https://wpitchoune.net/psensor/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know for number 1 but for number 2 you can configure this in BIOS.

Comment: I don't see a shutdown temp in the BIOS. However even if it were there, I want the OS to cleanly shut down or suspend so I don't lose work.